# Jenkins add pipelineTrigger after properties step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to ask how can I add a pipelineTrigger (example GenericTrigger from the Generic Webhook Trigger plugin) after the properties step is run. Typically I would use the `properties` step as per below

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        [$class: 'GenericTrigger',
        ...
    ])
})
```

However in my particular use case, I'm trying to add this trigger as part of a Global Pipeline Shared Library in Jenkins to add this pipeline trigger after a user calls a particular method. Using the `properties` step again will overwrite any property that was set earlier. I've tried getting the job and then using the `addProperty` method but it fails. Below is the snippet that I've tried.

```
def gen_trigger = pipelineTriggers([
        [$class: 'GenericTrigger',
        ...
    ])
])

def raw_build = currentBuild.getRawBuild()
def current_job = raw_build.getParent()
current_job.addProperty(gen_trigger)
```

The above snippet gives the following error. I've tried casting it to JobProperty type too but casting fails as expected.

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.addProperty() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable)`

Comment: Hey @impuls3h did you manage to solve this? I am in the exact same situation, seems impossible to set properties([]) and then try to modify them after..